# Что не так сделал, localhost:8080 выдает белый экран

Tags: jsp, maven, servlet, tomcat

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем моя проблема, задача звучит так: Создать 2 страницы, на одной - ввод имени, на второй - Hi + выведенное имя. Я новичок в программировании, и не могу разобраться. Все исходники прилагаются.

```
pom.xml 
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.maxim</groupId>
    <artifactId>tryweb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <path>/</path>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
    </project>
```

DemoServlet.java

```
package ru.maxim.tryweb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class DemoServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
doGet(request,response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Запрос");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write("<h4> Проба пера");
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>$Title$</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="/example/test" method="post">
    Enter name: <input type="text" name="name" value=""><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

redirect.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Redirect</title>
</head>
<body>
<b> Hello <%=request.getParameter("name")%></b>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DemoServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ru.maxim.tryweb.DemoServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Comment: а ошибок никаких нет?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо write написать println, вот так: "writer.println("<h4> Проба пера");".

Comment: @SonicMyst К сожалению, ничего не поменялось(

Comment: Почитайте вот это http://java-course.ru/student/book1/servlet/

Comment: Попрбуйте найти сервлет по адресу localhost8080:/имя_приложения/имя_сервлета